# NServiceBus Dynamic End Points

Tags: nservicebus

Is it possible to create end points dynamically at runtime.  E.g.  Send a message to a known endpoint with details of a new endpoint so that a network node can learn of new nodes on the fly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NServiceBus does not support this out of the box, but if you really really want it (and you are sure that it is the right way to go), you are free to implement your own message routing and send messages explicitly to an endpoint with `bus.Send(endpoint, message)`.

In a project I am currently involved with, we do this with great success, because it allows us to seamlessly sign services in and out of the system while it is running, resulting in zero downtime during upgrades.

It took a bit of work to get it working though, so I would only recommend this if you are certain that your requirements demand it.